# ¿Cómo cambio ese texto?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

¿Cómo cambio el texto de advertencia en Laravel 6? Necesito traducirlo a español.
Del `reset.blade.php`. Si necesitan más información por favor pídanla. También en caso de estar mal formulada la pregunta favor de avisarme, yo creo que con el código y la captura es más que suficiente para dar a entender.

[image: texto de alerta]

Este es el código del `reset.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Restablecimiento de contraseña') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.update') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ $email ?? old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Contraseña') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirma la contraseña') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Restablece la contraseña') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Creo se tiene que modificar la clase `invalid-feedback` pero no estoy seguro, demás no se conde se encuentre ese código.

Postdata: estoy usando plantillas blade en laravel.

Comment: tiene que estar en el html del componente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar dicho mensaje de validación en Laravel 6, debes crear otra carpeta `es` en `/resources/lang` y allí un archivo validation.php; Inicialmente encontrarás una carpeta allí llamada `en` (Inglés).

Asumiendo que hayas configurado correctamente el idioma de tu aplicación, entonces agregas un array de valores, que serán las traducciones equivalentes de esos mensajes de validación. en este caso, el nombre de dicha regla de validación es `confirmed`.

El contenido del archivo validation.php sería algo así, solo con esta validación:

```
<?php

return [
    'confirmed' => 'Mi mensaje personalizado',
];
```

Puedes tomar como ejemplo para todas las traducciones al español, el siguiente repositorio: https://github.com/Laraveles/spanish

Comment: No me mostraba los mensajes en español pero solo limpie la cache y ya los mostró, los dejo por si los necesitan `php artisan config:cache`, `php artisan cache:clear ` y `php artisan config:clear `